# how to restrict the bugs to move over the obstacle in andengine?

Tags: andengine

Hi i m using pathmodifier, to find the path of the sprite when it has reached its previous point.i want to move arround my sprite to different shapes of obstacle.. can anyone suggest me how to do it.. i tried with color pixel but it slow down my game performance.

For example [image: Bugs movement must be like arrowed line]

i drawed line arround the triangle , using the below formula i can find out the intersection point of bugs with this line

```
double d = (x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4);
 double xi = ((x3-x4)*(x1*y2-y1*x2)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/d;
 double yi = ((y3-y4)*(x1*y2-y1*x2)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/d;
.. but not working
```

can any one suggest me how to do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Consider asking the moderators to move the question to gamedev.stackexchange.com . I believe you'll get better answers there, assuming you add some tags.

Comment: It's been asked at gamdev too, so this question can be closed/removed.